# How to fix a Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c, loops, gcc, segmentation-fault, sentinel

Im writing a C program that is supposed to add every number until it hits a sentinel value. Then average it all together.

Im not sure where the problem is but I think it might be that num never actually changes. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int sentinal = 9999; 
int iterations = 0; 
int total = 0; 
int average; 
int num; 

int main(void){ 
do{ 
printf("Enter a number to add:\n"); 
scanf("%d\n", num); 
total = total + num; 
iterations++; 
}while (num != sentinal); 

average = total/iterations; 
printf("%d\n", average; 
return 0; 
}
```

Running version

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(){ 
int sentinel = 9999; 
int iterations = 0; 
int total = 0; 
float average; 
int num; 

while(1){ 
printf("\nEnter a number to add: "); 
scanf("%d", &num);
if (num == sentinel){
    break;
}else{
total = total + num; 
iterations++;} 
} 

average = (float) total/iterations; 
printf("%f\n", average; 
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: That requirement (parameters to `scanf` are by-address) is in quite literally every initial example of every text on the library function in existence. [See example and documentation here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). While fixing this, maybe try checking the result to ensure your out-parameter was properly extracted.

Comment: You are adding the sentinel into your total and counting it.  You probably don't want it as part of your sum and average.

Comment: Hint: check `scanf`, `printf` when printing `average`.

Comment: @Mel Moore: You tagged your question `gcc`, which implies that you are using GCC compiler. GCC issues a warning that pinpoints the primary problem in your code. Did you just ignore it?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help my I made a few edits to get it running and clean of logic errors.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the line:

```
scanf("%d\n", num);
```

`scanf` requires a memory address of the variable where should put the value the was read. This is done using the operator `&`. Your code should be:

```
scanf("%d\n", &num);
```

Answer (score 1):

scanf() takes a pointer to the value parsed from standard input. You're passing the actual value, not the pointer to the value.

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools in Linux to find out Segmentation and other compilers as well. If you want to really debug where your code is popping segmentation fault , you can use GDB and valgrind .It exactly gives you where you have error in your code .

Answer (score 1):

1. Provide address i.e. `&` when storing value using `scanf`.
2. Declare `average` as `float`, and while calculating `average` use `average = (float) total / iterations` and use `%f` while printing `average`.
3. Check your `printf` when you are printing `average`, closing bracket is missing.